# Is using a shield effective?

Tags: bloodborne

While playing, I came across a pretty crappy [wooden shield](http://bloodborne.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Shield).  When I played Dark Souls, I used the shield like my life depended on it. Not using one would pretty much lead to instant death, so it was invaluable.  Bloodborne, although similar to Dark Souls, seems to be more focused on combat rather than defense.  That being said, is there any real advantage to even using a shield?

Comment: This is the only shield in the game, and the in-game description of it is pretty much 'lol shields are bad'.

Comment: @GnomeSlice well that pretty much explains it! Thank you!

Comment: @GnomeSlice Consider writing that as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the shield is, as @GnomeSlice described in the comments, worthless. Also, I stumbled across an [article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/02/06/bloodborne-has-shields) with a quote from Masaaki Yamagiwa, one of the producers at Sony's Japan Studio.

> "There are shields in the game. However if you're always standing back and guarding, you'll die very quickly...  We wanted these encounters and battles to be so intense that If you just stand and wait, you'll get overwhelmed and killed right away. We wanted to encourage players to not hide and wait, but instead be more aggressive and pro-active in battle."

In other words, put down that shield and toss it into a fire.

Comment: Mhhh... I wonder if it can be useful if you are fighting enemies that rely on ranged attacks. Specifically, when you block a bullet, do you still get staggered?

Comment: @5pike, I tried blocking bullets with shield and it doesn't help much, you still take a lot of damage. I didn't find any advantages of using shield agains evasion.